# Unable to add apache-tomcat 8 in Eclipse EE

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, tomcat8, runtime-environment

When I try to add a new server into Eclipse, the option for Tomcat v8 server does not show up:
[screenshot tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIe0c.png)
So I've been trying to find a way to add the runtime environment, but it won't let me download available software.
I'm using an old version of Eclipse EE (20090920). Is there a way around this?

I tried to add Tomcat 8 from the Eclipse available software page, but it says the site could not be found:
[screenshot tomcat2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX4r4.png)
I have tried adding download.eclipse.org/releases/latest and it will not register either. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why such an old eclipse version ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat 8.x didn't exist until 2014. An Eclipse release from 2009 will not know that it exists, nor support it. You must use a newer release--preferably the current one, 2023-03, or a newer release when available. Newer releases can also download Tomcat for you.